# simple probability question - Independent experiments

Tags: probability

p=0.43

(1-p)=q=0.57

n=3

Its known that the first experiment failed.
what is the probability that the next experiments will succeed.

I'm thinking

P(X='Fail then success then success')=0.57*0.43*0.43

P(Y='Fail at the first time')=0.57

P(X/Y)=0.43^2

Is that correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but your working is more complicated than necessary.  Since experiments are independent, the fact that there has been one failure has no effect on future probabilities.  So all you want is
$$P(\hbox{$2$ successes from $2$ experiments})=(0.43)^2\ .$$